# Make button invisible onClick and show another button

Tags: html, reactjs, onclick

How can i make a button **invisible** in ReactJS once i click on it and show another button

```
  <button className ="btn" id="btnn"  onClick={this.onClick} >Ask a question </button>
```

and here is my attempt to do the onclick function which disables it

```
onClick= function() {
    btnn.disabled
}
```

Comment: hide or disable? which one you want to accomplish?

Comment: @NishantDixit Can you tell me both ways please

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(propss) {
    super(propss);
    this.state = {
      hide: false,
      disable: false
    };
    this.toggleButton = this.toggleButton.bind(this);
    this.disableButton = this.disableButton.bind(this);
  }

  toggleButton(value) {
    this.setState({ hide: value });
  }
  disableButton() {
    this.setState({ disable: true });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!this.state.hide && 
          <button onClick={() => this.toggleButton(true)}>Hide</button>
        }
        <button onClick={this.disableButton} disabled={this.state.disable}>
          disable
        </button>

      {(this.state.hide || this.state.disable) && (
      <button style={{ background: "green", color: "white" }}>
        New button
      </button>
    )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked! But how can i make another button appear once i click on the button i want to hide/disable?

Comment: I think above code full filling your requirement? or need something else?.

Comment: The thing is the above code does not show a new button once i click on the hide button for example.

Comment: Updated! check now.

Comment: Can you show me Link code which you are using instead of button?

Comment: Oh never mind a had a trivial mistake in my code and fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a state:

```
this.state = { invisible: false }
```

Then,

```
<button
    style={this.state.invisible ? {display:"none"} : {}} 
    className ="btn" id="btnn"  onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} >Ask a question 
</button>
<button
    style={!this.state.invisible ? {display:"none"} : {}} 
    className ="btn" id="btnn"  onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} >Other Button 
</button>
```

And,

```
onClick= function() {
    this.setState({ invisible: !this.state.invisible })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just create a state, that controls if your button will be shows or not. then you can use conditional rendering if the state is true..

```
   Something like ....


        Import React from 'react'

        class MyComponent extends React.Component ()
        {
        this.state {
        isClicked: false
        }

        this.setState(isClicked: true)
        render() {
          {isClicked} = this.state  
        return (
        // your code here

        {!isClicked &&
         <button className ="btn" id="btnn" onClick={this.onClick}> Ask a 
         question </button>
        } // will only display the button if the state is false, else if 
          state is true, it will not 
        );
        }}
```